# F# Visual Power Tools doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, f#, code-formatting

I'm trying to work with `F#`. For all projects in `VS2015` solution i want to have similar code style. I have installed [Visual F# Power Tools](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/) and setted formatting configuration to:[image]

According to this configuration (space after comma) the following code:

```
fun unit ->Log.Information( "Found: {category}\\{name}\\{instance}",category,name,instance )
```

should be converted to:

```
fun unit ->Log.Information( "Found: {category}\\{name}\\{instance}", category, name, instance )
```

But when i'm trying to format documment by pressing `Edit->Advanced->Format Document` nothing happend.

How to format my code?

**Update 1**

When i try to format the code i receive `Validation after formatting failed. The original content is preserved.` message:
[image]
I tried to search about this problem, and found [this issue](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/issues/202). 
May be some one faced with such problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Sanity check – is `Source code formatting` checked on the main PT options screen?

Comment: @ildjarn yes, `Source code formatting` check box is on

Comment: Two more sanity checks: Does the code currently compile; and have you restarted VS since setting up Power Tools?

Comment: @Kit absolutly yes. Code can be compiled and runned. I have restarted PC few times.

Comment: I have the same problem. For me, the code formatted fine until some random point and it just stopped out of a sudden. Even undoing does not change anything.

Comment: I can't edit my comment any more, but for me, it occurred when I had some very long string with escaped characters in. I split the string in shorter ones and used concatenation to get the long one, and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using namespaces. Below code does not format:

```
module Deck
type Color = 
    | Red
    | Green
    | Blue
    | Yellow
```

However, next one formats correctly

```
namespace Dummy

    module Deck = 
        type Color = 
            | Red
            | Green
            | Blue
            | Yellow
```