# F# code formatting: adjust spaces

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, f#, code-formatting

I use `VS2015` to write code in `F#`. I usually used `R#` to format `C#` code and now I try to find something similiar but for `F#`.

The main goal is to adjust spaces. For example

```
MethodName (var1,var2  )|> SomeMethod    |> SomeMethod
```

should be converted to :

```
MethodName ( var1, var2 ) |> SomeMethod |> SomeMethod
```

What tool can format my code in such manner?
How to do it?

**Update1**

I have tried `Visual F# Power Tools` and it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201311/f-visual-power-tools-doesnt-work) for me.

Thats why i asked here - to receive community opinion about different tools that can format code in `F#`

Comment: "F# Power Tools" extension is a necessity, you should definitely install it. But it can't do this particular kind of formatting.

Comment: Related question: [F# Visual Power Tools doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41201311/1243762)

Comment: After answering then finding your earlier question, the best advise I can give is that, 1. Fantomas is the only automated way I know of to format F# code. 2. For Fantomas to work the code has to compile cleanly as Fantomas does not work with the source code; I think it works with the AST but would have to check. Since Fantomas is open source and available at [GitHub](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas) you can always dig into the code and make changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was a duplicate question but could not find it.

The problem with finding the answer by searching such as with Google is that you run into [F# Formatting](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting) but that is not what you want.

The key is knowing that the project is named [fantomas](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas).

### How to install Fantomas

It can be installed as a stand alone extension but is more commonly installed as part of the [F# Power Tools](https://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/).

Using Visual Studio

From the VS menu
Tools -> Extensions and Updates...

[image]

[image]

In the left index click `Online`

[image]

In the search box in the upper right enter `F# Power Tools`

[image]

In the list in the middle select `Visual F# Power Tools`

[image]

Click `Download`

[image]

[image]

Click `Install`

[image]

Click `Restart Now`

Switch to the source code tab

### Quick demo of using Fantomas

Note: For this example I had to use different code than provided in the question because this only works with valid F# code and the code in the question was not valid F# code.

[image]

```
let somefunction x = x

let functionName   var1    var2 = var1   |> somefunction       |> somefunction
```

Ctrl-K, D  (Press Ctrl-K, then Ctrl-D)

[image]

```
let somefunction x = x

let functionName var1 var2 = 
    var1
    |> somefunction
    |> somefunction
```

### Setting options for Fantomas

From Visual Studio menu

Tools -> Options...

[image]

[image]

In left index scroll down and select `F# Power Tools`

[image]

Select `Formatting`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, i have tried  `Visual F# Poer Tools` and it doesn't work. 

My be you know how to force it to work? look into Update1

Comment: Also i suggest to install packages from console (it will be faster): `Install-Package FSharpVSPowerTools.Core`

Comment: Yes, i even tried to restart my PC - still doesn't work

Comment: thanks, i even have tryied to run commands vrom `VS` menu to make sure command was really called and had no success

Answer (score 2):

You could try Chris McGrath's `Code Alignment` extension, that's the one I use. It provides toolbar buttons which allow you to align the text on the selected lines by predefined or custom character strings.